# How to get Android Facebook Api

Tags: android, facebook

How do I import the fbconnect-android.zip into my project in eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Try: http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/wiki/Setup</strike>

The SDK documentation can be found at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: link is dead, please check from your side.

Comment: @RobinHood: This question and answer are nearly three years old. This particular project is dead. As Mr. Pearce indicates in another answer, there is an official Facebook SDK at this time that developers should use.

Answer (score 2):

Please, please, please... use the updated Facebook SDK for Android: https://developers.facebook.com/android/

There is a full 'getting started' guide to explain how to install it: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/