# steps of integrating Facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

How can we integrate Facebook in android?

Comment: What do you mean by integrating? Like accessing the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

download fbconnect first.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302460/android-facebook-api-how-to-get/2302557#2302557).....

you have create a account in developer.facebook.com. after that you get a API Key.

you can add this project with your project

right click your project-> properties->Select Projects tab-> Add Project--> both fbconnect-android and fbconnect-sample.

thats it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't integrate Facebook API from mobile.

Instead you should create your own web service and put somewhere on the web where you can update API changes more frequently than rolling out new mobile version of your app for each API changes. So the point here is that you keep API calls on the webserver where you can do immediate changes rather than pushing mobile updates through time consuming Markets approval.

Make that go (1) Android phone -> (2) your webserver file with Facebook API --> (3) Facebook Servers. You can find more examples working with Facebook API such as using PHP.

Comment: +1 Thats an interesting way of doing it. Is it to save time on your requests?

Comment: How would you handle authentication requests?

Comment: They can login via a webview that takes place between facebook and your server's page.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/).

Comment: yes i am looking for Facebook API.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use Social Libraries its very easy method to integrate FB, TWitter and Linked in. Am using the same and successfully able to integrate. check this: [here](http://code.google.com/p/sociallib/wiki/SocialLibGuide)