# How to connect or integrate facebook from android application

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [steps of integrating Facebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566371/steps-of-integrating-facebook-in-android)

Can anybody tell me how to connect to or integrate with Facebook from an android application?
Please give any sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Please check [this link][1] may be helpful. [1]:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Comment: Hey Mohan, please use the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=integrating+facebook+in+Android) feature before posting new questions. There are already several posts for this.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Check the [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/). It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Facebook [SDK for android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/)

This is SDK provided by Facebook for android you will also find sample code and applications in the same link

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953146/android-java-post-simple-text-to-facebook-wall) question

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sdk from [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/). This is a sample example of [android faceebook connectivity](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/)