# Facebook integration in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [steps of integrating Facebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566371/steps-of-integrating-facebook-in-android)

I want to integrate Facebook in my application where i want to share a link..can somebody tell me step by step how to integrate Facebook in your application using Facebook SDK...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently started an app that has Facebook integration. The link that Rosalie and basicsharp sent you is a step-by-step guide to getting Facebook integrated into your app. It took me a while to understand how the API fits together. The following link explains the Graph API, which is the core API that you will be using: [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Don't expect to get it right after 5mins, it will take time! Here is an overview of what you need to do to connect your app to facebook.

1. Get the facebook-android-api via Git(Just download it, it's
   extremely simple)
2. Create an existing project using the facebook api
3. Add Facebook Api as a reference via project options
4. Get your app's Hash key via cmd prompt(This is the trickier part,
   not going into it because there is an abundance of information
   regarding this topic)
5. Create Facebook app(On Facebook)
6. Do the code - [Facebook developer mobile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)

And there you have it.