# How to work on facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am going to work on Facebook in android. But i do not have any idea how to start it. Is there any special SDK for it. How can i make a game stay alive on facebook ?

Anyone having please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [steps of integrating Facebook in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566371/steps-of-integrating-facebook-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the facebook-android sdk:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Additionally, there's a [getting started tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/) for Android applications that want to use Facebook.